# Extract any 5 digit number from a String using Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to use REGEX to pull a 5 digit number from a larger String.

Here is the method I am using to do this however it simply returns null.

```
public void setCWBudgetCode(String webPage){

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\\b\\d{5}\b/g");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(webPage);
    if (matcher.find())
        this.cwBudgetCode = matcher.group();
}
```

Comment: There is no group 1 in your regex. Just use `group()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\\b\\d{5}\\b/g");
```

Instead of that use this `pattern`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\b\\d{5}\\b)");
```

Unlike Javascript there is no regex delimiter in Java and of course no `/g`

Also note I have use `parenthesis` around regex so that you can use `matcher.group(1)`

Comment: It won't work, because the OP is getting the group with `matcher.group(1)` while there is no group 1. He should use `group()`

Comment: Strange, it's still not passing the if condition, and I'm testing it using Strings like "A bunch of text 12345"

Comment: @BackSlash: Yes I realized that was also the mistake but first error was of course OP's wrong regex.

Comment: Don't put parenthesis, just use `group()`.

Comment: Actually I am amused at all the emphasis on `group()` va `group(1)`. If OP's regex is wrong none of that will even execute since `find()` will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your Regex to save the number as a group `Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d{5})\\b");`

this will make it work with your `group(1)` code below